# Contribution of regressors in regression with ARMA error

Tags: regression, forecasting, arima, granger-causality, dynamic-regression

I am trying to forecast 'Patients' by fitting linear regression with ARMA error (auto.arima, Xreg) with 5 regressors. 'patients' and all 5 regressors have seasonality.

1) Is there any way to quantify the percent contribution of each regressor in both historical data and forecast?

2) Can I rely on coefficient of regression while I know that regressors are not orthogonal?

3) Would increase in F test on R squared (Granger test) show the contribution of each regressor if I add regressors one by one?